# mTLS between services in K8S

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager, mtls

I would like to enable mTLS between services in one K8S namespace. I wonder if I can do it without using service mesh? I considered cert-manager but all the examples I've seen involved Ingress resource which I do not need as my services are not exposed outside of the cluster.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using *Service Mesh* like [Istio](https://istio.io/) or [Linkerd](https://linkerd.io/) for this is currently the only general solution for this.

It should be possible to do this using a library for you app as well, the library typically would need to support certificate management. *Service Meshes* typically use EnvoyProxy as a sidecar, it has implemented novel "control plane" APIs for management, called [xDS protocols](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-docs/xds_protocol) - this is something that your library typically would need to implement. In addition you need a control plane interface to manage services.

A drawback with doing this in a library is that it will be language-dependent. But the pro is that it will be better performant.

Google has recently taking this route with [Traffic Director - proxyless service mesh](https://cloud.google.com/traffic-director/docs/proxyless-overview)

Comment: Thanks! does cert-manager will work with internal services?

Comment: I don't think cert-manager is designed for mTLS, no.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [SPIRE](https://spiffe.io/docs/latest/spire-about/spire-concepts/) together with [SPIRE integration operator](https://github.com/otterize/spire-integration-operator). Together, they can create mTLS keys and certificates for use within a cluster, where the only configuration you need is pod annotations. The mTLS keypairs are provided as secrets, which you mount into your pods. SPIRE & the operator automatically handle keypair and CA rotation and update the Secrets accordingly.